# Access telegram views via bots

Tags: api, view, telegram

How we could access groups/channel views in telegram for bot is there any API or solution?

I searched so much in net but nothing found

Also is There Any way that bot could delete a post??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently in telegram api ver.3 delete message added

Answer (score 1):

[Telegram bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) doesn't have any permission to delete a message (only `edit` for **update**).

Also you can't access to post view by bot API. you can get `only channel members count` by bot API.

Answer (score 0):

[Telegram official API](https://core.telegram.org/methods)

Firstly take a look on link above.
For deleting post probably you should use `messages.deleteMessages` method